# How to delete glacier object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have created a s3 life cycle policy which will `Expire the current version of the object in 540 days`.

I am a bit confused here, whether it deletes the objects from s3 or glacier,
if not I want to delete the objects from a bucket in 540 days and the glacier in some 4 years! how will I set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expiring an object means "delete it", regardless of its storage class.

So, if it has moved to a Glacier storage class, it will still be deleted.

When you store data in Glacier via S3, then the object is managed by Amazon S3 (but stored in Glacier). Thus, the lifecycle rules apply.

If, however, you store data directly in Amazon Glacier (without going via Amazon S3), then the data would not be impacted by the lifecycle rules, nor would it be visible in Amazon S3.

**Bottom line:** Set your rules for deletion based upon the importance of the data, not its current storage class.

Comment: Thanks

but later if I want to delete the object from glacier also how can I do that.

Comment: If an object in Amazon S3 is moved to a storage class of `Glacier`, then it is still managed by Amazon S3. Just think of it like moving to a cheaper disk. If the object is deleted from S3, it is deleted regardless of the storage class. This means that an object with a storage class of `Glacier` is also deleted from Glacier when it is deleted from S3.

Comment: It might be easy-peasy, I was just a little bit confused,
Thanks now!